# function moveon() - Javascript the definitive guide 6/E

Tags: javascript

In my book - Javascript the definitive guide 6/e, want me to type the code in HTML file but it doesn't work.

The code is as follows:

```
<script>
function moveon(){
var answer = confirm("Ready to move on?");
if (answer) window.location = "http://google.com";
}
</script>
```

The Modal Dialog box never shows up in my chrome.

I just start to learn Javascript by myself, so thanks in advance for answering!

Comment: where's the trigger of the method?

Comment: You might have to call the moveon

Comment: Thank you, guys. I didn't close the moveon. now it works well! Hope you guys have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

You have only declared the function, but the function is never executed. In order for the code to run, you need to call the function, like so: `moveon();`

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Is this code, right?

<code>
<script>
   moveon();
       var answer = confirm("Ready to move on?");
       if (answer) window.location = "http://google.com";
</script>

Comment: @Jiu.Ha add it after the declaration.

<script>
function moveon(){
var answer = confirm("Ready to move on?");
if (answer) window.location = "http://google.com";
}
moveon();
</script>

Comment: ...and you can check @Dhaval's answer above for an alternative implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52962423/3504096

Answer (score 1):

you need to call the method moveon() somewhere in your code, check below code which calls moveon method on button click.

but if you are using url other then your current domain and getting error in console please check [Same-Origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

```js
function moveon(){
    var answer = confirm("Ready to move on?");
    if (answer) {
        window.location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="move on" onclick="moveon();"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer! I just try it and it works!!!
Hope you have a wonderful wonderful day :)